# Is there a way to assert current namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, macros

For example suppose I have a macro

```
#define DEFINE_VAL(x) int x
```

I want to assert the macro is only used in certain namespace, is there a way to achieve that?

In another word, I want something like:

```
#define DEFINE_VAL(x) static_assert(CurrentNamespaceIsXYZ); int x
```

Or

```
#define DEFINE_VAL(x) ASSERT_CURRENT_NAMESPACE_IS(XYZ); int x
```

How to implement/define CurrentNamespaceIsXYZ or ASSERT_CURRENT_NAMESPACE_IS ?

Comment: The short answer is: no. The preprocessing phase generally occurs before the compilation phase, at which namespace, and other language constructs, actually get parsed. Perhaps you can now explain [what is your real XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: You can #undefine the symbol at entry to where ever it is not desired.  Which could be a lot of work.  Don't use macros.

Comment: I have revised the question, could you take another look? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just check if an unqualified type is the same type as a qualified type.

```
#DEFINE_VAL(x)                  \
   struct TEST;                 \
   static_assert(std::is_same<TEST, ::CurrentNamespaceIsXYZ::TEST>::value, \
                 "Not in XYZ);  \
   int x
```

Probably best to suffix a GUID to `TEST`, to provide name clashes.